# Configure GZip compression in Apache server

Tags: php, apache, compression, gzip, google-pagespeed

I add the following code on my htaccces file but if I check my page on gzip compression test. No Compression..

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

I have also tried below code

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

I searched alot and tried other mod or deflate codes but none of them work. What do I do to enable gzip compression?

**In google page speed tool I am geeting gzip in request header but in response content is not encoded in gzip**

Comment: Show the Google Page Speed Tool output and which resource is showing as not being gzipped.

Comment: In Google page speed tool all CSS, JS and php files are listed without compression

Comment: Second config looks good. Though not sure what your php files are returning as (text/html?). I presume you are including mod_deflate file? Mod_gzip is not used anymore.

Comment: in httpd.conf file, mod_deflate is included and in htaccess file 2nd config is added. Then also I am not getting compressed response.

Comment: Google page speed o/p: **Response :** Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Mon, 19 Dec 2016 11:17:50 GMT
ETag:"1a70-543afb1d9745a-gzip"
Expires:Wed, 18 Jan 2017 11:17:50 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=95
Last-Modified:Thu, 15 Dec 2016 10:12:45 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.29
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
**Request Headers**
view source
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br

Comment: Difficult to read that. Better to edit the question to add that sort of detail. But that's a png file and it is NOT gzipped according to those headers. But then again png files shouldn't be (as they are already compress) and not in your config - so wouldn't expect them to be gzipped.